# Is there a way to restrict the no of partitions initialize per consumer in Event hubs

Tags: c#, azure-eventhub

I have a C# Windows Service which is installed in 3 different servers. All these 3 services are registering to the same event hub which has 8 partitions. In a way these 3 servers are my consumers. Once I start the windows service, multiple partitions can initialized in different servers. This initialization is always random as far as I have observed.

Say the initialization scenario is like below :

Server1 : Partition 0,1,2
Server2 : Partition 3,4
Server3 : Partition 5,6,7

This initialization happens through this code :

```
  public Task OpenAsync(PartitionContext context)
    {
       Console.WriteLine($"SimpleEventProcessor initialized. Partition: '{context.PartitionId}'");
       return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
```

My requirement is, even though there are multiple partitions, I want to initialize only one partition per consumer/server. Is there a way to restrict all partitions from getting initialized?

What I thought is, there might be some in build feature which counts and tells the no of partitions already initialized. So I can use to check if the value is "1", then skip initializing others partitions. But I couldn't find any such feature.

Since I have 3 servers, I want only 3 partitions to get initialized, one in each server. Rest of the 5 will be free and will not receive any messages. Those can be used in the future when the number of servers increase.

Is this scenario possible?

Comment: A general advice, given the question you asked so far, is to reconsider the chosen service. I really think Event Hub isn't the best solution for your requirements. That said let me answer some details: *Rest of the 5 will be free and will not receive any messages.* -> this only works if you modify the sending parties to only send events to specific partitions, otherwise some messages might never be picked up. By default, all messages are distributed evenly over the provided partitions . But again, you are really working around the capabilities en design principles of the azure event hub.

Answer (score 1):

If that is your requirement then you are on wrong SDK. Processor Host SDK is designed to consumer from all partitions and it won't let you constrain interluding partition manager easily.

I recommend you to use low level API so that you can create independent receivers on any partition you like. You will have way better control on partition management this way.

```
var receiver = eventHubClient.CreateReceiver(PartitionReceiver.DefaultConsumerGroupName, partitionId, PartitionReceiver.EndOfStream);

// Receive a maximum of 100 messages in this call to ReceiveAsync
var ehEvents = await receiver.ReceiveAsync(100);

// ReceiveAsync can return null if there are no messages
if (ehEvents != null)
{
    // Since ReceiveAsync can return more than a single event you will need a loop to process
    foreach (var ehEvent in ehEvents)
    {
        // Decode the byte array segment
        var message = UnicodeEncoding.UTF8.GetString(ehEvent.Body.Array);
        // Load the custom property that we set in the send example
        var customType = ehEvent.Properties["Type"];
        // Implement processing logic here
    }
}
```